# ASP.Net Core 2: Clon de titulo de tabla? @viewdata copypasteado?

Tags: asp.net-core

pasa que el titulo de esta tabla esta clonado? Ya revisé los ViewDatas que no haya alguno clonado/copy-pasteado.

Alguna sugerencia? 
[image: Descripcion clonado]
Modelo Categoria
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Vista Index
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si puedes pon el código de tu vista

Comment: @VicenteAlmea En el modelo de la vista hay una **descripcion** que si se edita, al momento de cargar el proyecto, en la vista  cambia la parte de `[Display(name="Descripicion")]` 
Ejemplo: `[Display(Name="Descripcion12345")]` y en la ejecucion cambia, si comento esa linea, sigue apareciendo el Descripcion clonado.

Comment: Solucionado gracias, estaba pulleando descipcion desde la vista index. Gracias de todas formas

Comment: 3 cosas: 1. Edita la pregunta colocando código en vez de imágenes, 2. Agrega la respuesta a tu pregunta. 3. Espera 24-48 horas y acepta la respuesta para mantener la buena salud del sitio. Gracias :D